# Mysql - Auto create, update, delete table 2 from table 1

Tags: mysql

Hi i need to Mysql Auto create, update, delete table 2 from table 1
I have table 1 which column is:

```
id, title, category, sku, brand, price, last_update
```

And i have table 2 which column is:

```
id, title, sku, brand, code1, code2
```

What i need to if table a insert new value or update or delete will affect to table 2, how can i do that ?
I try this :

```
INSERT INTO table2 (title, sku, brand)
SELECT title, sku, brand
FROM table1
```

But this not good idea because when i run agaain sql much duplicate i have and i can not update it, please tell me how do that.

Answer (score 0):

Iam using trigger to solved my problem :

```
CREATE TRIGGER table1insert after INSERT ON table1
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 INSERT INTO table2 SET
 title = NEW.title, sku=New.sku, brand=NEW.brand
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sku=New.sku;
 END$$
```

and i make one again trigger if table 1 delete so table 2 deleted too.

```
CREATE TRIGGER table1delete after DELETE ON table1
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     DELETE FROM table2
     WHERE sku=old.sku;
     END$$
```

maybe this can help everyone need it